# return elements from a vuejs method

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm a bit new to vuejs and I'm not even sure what exactly am I looking for,
I have this template:

```
<template>
    <md-content class="md-elevation-2">
        <div class="md-layout">
            <div class="md-layout-item" v-for="key in ruleData">
                {{ getKeyOutput(key) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </md-content>
</template>
```

and my script is:

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['ruleData'],
        methods: {
            getKeyOutput(value) {
                switch (typeof value) {
                    case 'string':
                        if (/(ban)$/g.test(value)) {
                            return createElement(`<h1>${ value }</h1>`)  // here is the problem
                        } else {
                            return value
                        }
                        break
                    case 'number':
                        return String(value)
                        break
                    case 'boolean':
                        return String(value)
                        break
                    default:
                        return value
                        break
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

What I want to do is on some case return the string, and in some other cases like return an HTML component like h1 for example, and I can't seem to understand how I need to do this, or even if I have the correct approach for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `v-html` directive to render html tags that is stored as a string.

if you don't use `v-html` then vuejs by default escapes the html tags and therefore the html tags are displayed as a plain text. You don't need to use `createElement()` at anyplace in your code, just remove it.

Change your vue template code as below and verify if you are getting the expected result

```
<div 
    class="md-layout-item" 
    v-for="(value,key) in ruleData" 
    :key="key" 
    v-html="getKeyOutput(value)">
</div>
```

You don't need to use `createElement()` anymore, just return the html code as a `string` or `template string`

```
if (/(ban)$/g.test(value)) {
    return `<h1>${ value }</h1>`; //problem solved
 } else {
    return value
 }
```

**Read More details about `v-html` in the docs** https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML